# How can I find the current in the resistor,when I found inductor current in this question?

Tags: current, resistors, inductor, step-response

[image]

Previous part of the question, I found the inductor current (from natural and step force). But here, I think it asks 10 ohm resistor's current. How can I  find it ?

Comment: What does R/L mean to you?

Comment: what kind of question is this?

Comment: @JuanDoe I think this is the usual transient and steady-state circuit analysis type question.

Comment: Do you know how to figure out the resistor current at t=0+? And at t= infinity? Then you just need to figure out which of the choices fits those constraints.

Answer (score 1):

At steady state, the switch is at position 'b'. In this circuit, you may calculate the inductor current at t<0. Since the inductor current can't change instantaneously as the switch is changed to position 'a', for t=0+, the inductor current will be the same. With switch at position 'b', a nodal analysis will get you the common node voltage and from that, you may compute the current in the resistor, which is the same as the one marked correct on your grading sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the inductor current equation for \$t > 0\$ then you can easily find the voltage across the resistor for \$t > 0\$ using the fundamental equation of the inductor.

$$v = L\frac{di}{dt}$$